# Can Python code be included into the body of NetLogo code?

Tags: python, embed, netlogo

As the title suggests, I am looking for a way to embed Python code into NetLogo. So far I have found the [NetLogo Python](https://github.com/NetLogo/Python-Extension) extension but from my understanding this extension only runs in the NetLogo prompt below (where you put the Observer/Turtle/etc. commands), so more like a built-in interpreter.

My question is whether there is a way, using this extension or otherwise, to embed Python code into the body of a NetLogo project, for example like this:

```
; This is an extract of some method/subroutine
  print global-peopleNum

  (py:run
    "print('hello')"
  )

  set-patch-size 20
; other regular NetLogo code
```

so that it resembles compiled code as opposed to interpreted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can embed Python code directly into NetLogo code using the Python extension, it is not usable only through the command center. Check out the [Python Basic Example](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/PythonBasicExample) and [Python Flocking Clusters](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/PythonFlockingClusters) models that come with NetLogo in the models library.

Here is the code from the Python Basic Example model:

```
extensions [ py ]

to setup ; Here we setup the connection to python and import a few libraries
  py:setup py:python
  py:run "import math"
  py:run "import sys"
  py:run "import os"
  reset-ticks
end

to go ; make sure everything is ready to go!
  py:run "print('go!')"
end

to get-sys-info ; Here we use the `sys` package in python to output some system info
  output-print (word "Python directory: " (py:runresult "sys.prefix"))
  output-print (word "Platform: " (py:runresult "sys.platform"))
  output-print (word "Python copyright: " (py:runresult "sys.copyright"))
  output-print ""
end

to gcd ; Use the `math` package's built-in gcd method to calculate the gcd(a,b)
  py:set "a" a
  py:set "b" b
  let result py:runresult "math.gcd(a, b)"
  output-print (word "Greatest common divisor of " a " and " b " is: " result)
  output-print ""
end

to get-home-directory ; Use the `os` package to get the home directory of the system
  let home-dir py:runresult "os.environ['HOME']"
  output-print (word "Current home directory is: " home-dir)
  output-print ""
end

to join-strings ; join some strings in python
  let result joined-strings
  output-print (word "Here they are joined: " result)
  output-print ""
end

to-report joined-strings ; helper procedure to join strings using a delimiter
  py:set "delim" delimiter
  py:set "list" read-from-string string-list
  report py:runresult "delim.join(list)"
end

to to-upper-case ; upper case some Strings in Python
  let result joined-strings
  py:set "result" result
  set result py:runresult "result.upper()"
  output-print (word "Here they are in upper case: " result)
  output-print ""
end
```